# Why dwell when checking for leaks on AMS-02?

Tags: procedure, in-space-repairs, alpha-magnetic-spectrometer

On [spacewalk 4/4](https://youtu.be/cOzMVW1GdDc) of the AMS-02 repair mission, Luca discovered a leak in one of the spliced coolant lines. They then had to wait an hour after a repair before re-testing the joint; a 'mandatory dwell'. Why was this necessary?

Comment: Did they wait an hour before repairing, or wait an hour after repairing for re-test?

Comment: @RussellBorogove Good point, I messed up the order; it's the latter.

Comment: Well, what did the repair involve?  Anything that requires cooling, relaxing, completion of chemical reaction (epoxy, e.g.) won't be fully complete for some period of time.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It seemed to be purely mechanical: a swage joint on stainless tubing was tightened a quarter turn - sorry, I should have added that to the question.

Comment: @OxDBFB7 If you want to know the real and detailed answer, you can binge watch the series "Among the Stars" on Disney+, I've seen the whole thing, and It's a great watch! I highly reccomend it to those who are curious about how AMS was repaired! It is a little dramatic though... only in some places!